# Can MVC 4 run on .net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

My server only supports ASP .NET 3.5 max. I am learning to develop MVC 4. 
Is it possible to run MVC 4 on a .NET 3.5 machine?
Of course I have no right to alter the server machine's configuration.
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It use components which was implemented in higher framework versions and will not be available.

This is requirements for MVC 4:

> System requirements Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows
>   Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit x86), Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 editions,
>   Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2008, Windows
>   Server 2008 R2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2, Windows XP Service Pack
>   3
>
> PowerShell 2.0, .NET 4, ASP.NET 4, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 or
>   Visual Web Developer 2010 SP1 are required to use this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, you cannot. ASP.NET MVC 3 and 4 both require the .NET Framework 4.0 (they also require Visual Studio 2010 or later; if you're using VS2008 and/or .NET 3.5 then you're stuck with ASP.NET MVC 2.0).

Out of curiosity, what server are you running? Windows Server 2003, with the exception of Small Business Server 2003, [fully supports the .NET Framework 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The next older OS is Windows 2000, but that doesn't run .NET 3.5. My only other guess is that you have a crappy webhost?

Answer (score 0):

MVC 4 targets the .NET 4.5 framework. Check out this Q&A for a little more detail: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157717/what-is-dependency-of-asp-net-mvc-on-net-framework-and-how-to-use-it-with-net